# Is there a way to solve git "fatal" problem?

Tags: git, github

I just finished my homework this afternoon, and I want to push the code into my github.

The code I wrote is:

```
>>git init
>>git add .
>>git status
>>git commit -m "the first version of code"
>>git remote add origin "https://github.com/riederleeDEV/CS41-Stanford.git/"
>>git push -u origin master
```

then I got this problem

How to fix it? Thank you so much!

```
remote: Permission to riederleeDEV/CS41-Stanford.git denied to LogenLi.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/riederleeDEV/CS41-Stanford.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: Do you own the repo or have permissions to push to it?

Comment: I have a repo for sure. I created one. But how to check the permission? @MaazSyedAdeeb

Comment: If you own the repo, then you'll definitely have access. Let me be more specific. Does the user, you're trying to push as to GitHub, own the https://github.com/riederleeDEV/CS41-Stanford.git/ repo?

Comment: This error means the key you are pushing with is attached to another repository as a deploy key, and does not have access to the repository you are trying to push to.

To fix this, remove the deploy key from the repository, and add the key to your user account instead.

If the key you are using is intended to be a deploy key, check out our guide on deploy keys for more details.

Comment: You might want to check for existing ssh keys https://help.github.com/articles/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys/

Comment: I own this repo. It is in my github. Did I do something wrong when i created it?

Comment: It is really weird

Comment: If it is your repo then after git commit directly push the project using git push.

Comment: Do you use ssh to push to your github repo ?

Comment: Your error says _denied to LogenLi_. Are you logged in as another user?

Comment: Do you think the problem is because of github or git because I checked on the website that git also has a user name. But I am pretty sure there should be no problem in my github as all my info is consistent

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a mismatch with your credentials. As per your URL, you're using `https` to connect to GitHub. Which is basically authenticated via a username and password. You need to have `user.email` set to the same email id as the one used to create the GitHub account.

To set the email id:

```
git config --global user.mail "youremail@email.com"
```

Then, make sure you login with same account when doing `git push`.

Also, make sure the commits you're trying to push are made using the same email. If you want to modify history, you can follow [this](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/).

Comment: Hi there! I just check my git --config. It shows that everything is consistent with my github info. But still it shoes me Logenli stuff. What is happening

Comment: credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.mail= rightemail
user.name=Rieder
user.email= rightemail
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/riederleeDEV/CS41-Stanford.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Comment: I do not know where Logenli come from